# Query SQL para omitir todos registros de coumna 1 pendiendo de algunos de la columna 2

Tags: sql

En el siguiente ejemplo, me gustaría excluir todos los **Recibos** que contengan cualquier registro con valor 'H'. En este caso todos los recibos cuyo valor sea AAAA (al tener al menos un Valor 'H', quiero que desaparezcan esas 4 filas con 'AAAA')

[image: Recibo Valor AAAA H AAAA H AAAA Z AAAA Z BBBB Z BBBB Z BBBB Z BBBB Z BBBB Z BBBB Z CCCC L CCCC L CCCC L CCCC L]

¿Cómo podría hacerlo en una consulta SQL que se extienda a cientos de registros donde la letra H puede aparecer decenas de veces?

Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Comment: Pero solo tienes 2 filas cuyo Valor es H, bajo que criterio habría que hacer que no te aparecieran las 4 filas con AAAA si las ultimas 2 su valor es Z, o Z también entraría en tu restricción?

Comment: Por lo pronto existe la sentencia NOT IN () en la cual debes especificar un criterio y para nuestro caso sería ``SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo NOT IN ('valor')``

Comment: Hola! lo primero agradecerte la respuesta. Efectivamente, el valor H debería afectar a todos los registros cuyo recibo sea AAAA, es decir, desaparecerian las filas de AAAA-H y AAAA-Z (quedando solo los recibos BBBB y CCCC en este ejemplo. Por eso no soy capaz de conseguir este resultado, porque los filtros solo me quitan las filas con registros de valor H. Voy experimentar con el NOT IN a ver si lo consigo!

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código que has intentado

Answer (score 1):

***EDITO:** En la primera respuesta había entendido **"borrar"** en lugar de **"Excluir"**. La idea es la misma, pero modifico los `DELETE` por `SELECT` y poner la condición al contrario.*

Debes hacerlo en 2 pasos:

1. Conseguir saber qué valores de la columna `RECIBO` tienen una `'H'` en la columna `VALOR`.
2. Excluir todos los registros cuyo dato en la columna `RECIBO` sea uno de los obtenido en el punto anterior.

Puedes utilizar un `SELECT..IN` (esta forma es más simple de entender):

```
SELECT *  FROM TABLAREC WHERE RECIBO NOT IN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT RECIBO FROM TABLAREC WHERE VALOR='H')
```

También puedes emplear una `JOIN`, que la hará más ***eficiente*** (aunque un poco más compleaja de entender):

```
SELECT TC.* FROM TABLAREC TC 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT RECIBO FROM TABLAREC WHERE VALOR='H')   
  TT ON (TT.RECIBO<>TC.RECIBO)
```

Ambas deberían dar el resultado que esperas. en este caso, 10 registros (todos menos los que contienen `AAAA`).

Comment: ¿Y como hará cuando quiera ver esos datos que ya borraste?

Comment: Perdón, había leído mal la pregunta, en lugar de "Excluir" había entendido "Borrar". Modifico la respuesta. Gracias Luis.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, ayúdanos a mantener la calidad del sitio respondiendo preguntas basadas en [ask], saludos.

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta está bastante clara, no creo que falle la explicación. En mi caso, la respuesta ha sido errónea por una mala lectura por mi parte.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Me ha dado el resultado esperado :)

Answer (score 1):

Para esto puedes hacer una subconsulta relacionada usando `EXISTS()`.

```
SELECT *
FROM MiTabla t
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT *
                  FROM MiTabla i
                  WHERE i.Recibo = t.Recibo
                  AND   i.valor  = 'H');
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, ayúdanos a mantener la calidad del sitio respondiendo preguntas basadas en [ask], saludos.